# Do I need caching after repartitining

Tags: caching, apache-spark

I have madde a dataaframe which I repartitined based on its primary key on the nodes

```
val config=new SparkConf().setAppName("MyHbaseLoader").setMaster("local[10]")
val context=new SparkContext(config)
val sqlContext=new SQLContext(context)
val rows="sender,time,time(utc),reason,context-uuid,rat,cell-id,first-pkt,last-pkt,protocol,sub-proto,application-id,server-ip,server-domain-name, http-proxy-ip,http-proxy-domain-name, video,packets-dw, packets-ul, bytes-dw, bytes-ul"
val scheme= new StructType(rows.split(",").map(e=>new StructField(e.trim,StringType,true)))
val dFrame=sqlContext.read
  .schema(scheme)
  .format("csv")
  .load("E:\\Users\\Mehdi\\Downloads\\ProbDocument\\ProbDocument\\ggsn_cdr.csv")

dFrame.registerTempTable("GSSN")
dFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val distincCount=sqlContext.sql("select count(distinct sender) as SENDERS from GSSN").collectAsList().get(0).get(0).asInstanceOf[Long]
dFrame.repartition(distincCount.toInt/3,dFrame("sender"))
```

Do I need to call my presist method again after repartitioning for next reducing jobs on dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `repartition` returns a new DataFrame so you would need to `cache` it again.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by Dikei seems to address your direct question it is important to note that in a case like this there is typically no reason to explicitly cache at all.

Every shuffle in Spark (here it is `repartition`) serves as an implicit caching point. If some part of lineage has to be re-executed and none of the executors has been lost you it won't have to go further back than to the last shuffle and read shuffle files.

It means that caching just before or just after a shuffle is typically a waste of time and resources especially if you're not interested in in-memory only or some non standard caching mechanism.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there's no caching during shuffle, only the result of the map phase is put to disk. It's fast to recompute the ShuffleRDD from these files if they're in OS cache, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Dikei You're not wrong, but it doesn't affect my opinion. If OP accepts writes to disk from the beginning putting potentially the same data to disk twice is quite wasteful. And since caching is neither free nor guaranteed I don't see any reason for such a  redundancy here. It it was in-memory only or off-heap then maybe... I could be wrong though. Do you think it really makes sense here?

Comment: I think it depends on what the rest of the program does.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to persist the reparation DataFrame, since DataFrames are immutable and reparation returns a new DataFrame.

A approach which you could follow is to persist dFrame and after its reparation the new DataFrame which returned is dFrameRepart. At this stage you could persist the dFrameRepart and unpersist the dFrame in order to free up the memory, provided that you won't be using dFrame again. In case your using dFrame after the reparation operation , both the DataFrames can be persisted.

dFrame.registerTempTable("GSSN")
dFrame.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val distincCount=sqlContext.sql("select count(distinct sender) as SENDERS from GSSN").collectAsList().get(0).get(0).asInstanceOf[Long]

valdFrameRepart=dFrame.repartition(distincCount.toInt/3, dFrame("sender")).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
dFrame.unpersist